# How to constrain touches to specific aspect ratio?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, crop, touchesmoved

I need to draw a selection rectangle to specific aspect ratios (square, 4x3, 5x7, 8x10, etc) so I can crop the image. I've got some pretty normal code that handles dragging the 4 corners of the rectangle freely inside touchesBegan/Moved, but I'm having a hell of a time getting it to constrain to specific aspect ratios without it creeping, or not being accurate.

Here's some pseudo-code of what I currently have:

```
// this assumes that the four hitPoints are already arranged in the desired aspect ratio 

CGPoint hitPoints[4]; // arranged botLeft=0, botRight=1, topRight=2, topLeft=3
CGPoint lastPoint;
CGRect cropRect;
int activeHitPoint;

#define kMinCropSize 20

- (void) touchesBegan
{
    lastPoint = [touches locationInView:self];
    activeHitPoint = [self getWhichPointTouched];
}

- (void) touchesMoved
{
    CGPoint thisPoint = [touches locationInView:self];
    float xDiff = thisPoint.x - lastPoint.x;
    float yDiff = thisPoint.y - lastPoint.y;

    float constrain = [self getAspectRatio];  // e.g.. 8x10  = 8/10 = 0.8 

    if(ABS(xDiff) > ABS(yDiff)){
        yDiff = xDiff * constrain;
        if(activeHitPoint == 1 || activeHitPoint == 3)
            yDiff *= -1;
    }else {
        xDiff = yDiff * constrain;
        if(activeHitPoint == 1 || activeHitPoint == 3)
            xDiff *= -1;
    }

    switch(activeHitPoint){
        case 0:
        if((hitPoints[0].x + xDiff > imageDisplayRect.origin.x) &&
           (hitPoints[0].x + xDiff + kMinCropSize < hitPoints[1].x) &&
           (hitPoints[0].y + yDiff > imageDisplayRect.origin.y) &&
           (hitPoints[0].y + yDiff + kMinCropSize < hitPoints[2].y)){
                hitPoints[0].x += xDiff;
                hitPoints[0].y += yDiff;
                hitPoints[3].x = hitPoints[0].x;
                hitPoints[1].y = hitPoints[0].y;
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        if((hitPoints[1].x + xDiff < imageDisplayRect.origin.x + imageDisplayRect.size.width) &&
           (hitPoints[1].x + xDiff - kMinCropSize > hitPoints[0].x) &&
           (hitPoints[1].y + yDiff > imageDisplayRect.origin.y) &&
           (hitPoints[1].y + yDiff + kMinCropSize < hitPoints[2].y)){
                hitPoints[1].x += xDiff;
                hitPoints[1].y += yDiff;
                hitPoints[2].x = hitPoints[1].x;
                hitPoints[0].y = hitPoints[1].y;
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        if((hitPoints[2].x + xDiff < imageDisplayRect.origin.x + imageDisplayRect.size.width) &&
           (hitPoints[2].x + xDiff - kMinCropSize > hitPoints[0].x) &&
           (hitPoints[2].y + yDiff < imageDisplayRect.origin.y + imageDisplayRect.size.height) &&
           (hitPoints[2].y + yDiff - kMinCropSize > hitPoints[1].y)){
                hitPoints[2].x += xDiff;
                hitPoints[2].y += yDiff;
                hitPoints[1].x = hitPoints[2].x;
                hitPoints[3].y = hitPoints[2].y;
        }
        break;
        case 3:
        if((hitPoints[3].x + xDiff > imageDisplayRect.origin.x) &&
           (hitPoints[3].x + xDiff + kMinCropSize < hitPoints[2].x) &&
           (hitPoints[3].y + yDiff < imageDisplayRect.origin.y + imageDisplayRect.size.height) &&
           (hitPoints[3].y + yDiff - kMinCropSize > hitPoints[0].y)){
                hitPoints[3].x += xDiff;
                hitPoints[3].y += yDiff;
                hitPoints[0].x = hitPoints[3].x;
                hitPoints[2].y = hitPoints[3].y;
        }
        break;
    }

    cropRect = CGRectMake(hitPoints[0].x, hitPoints[0].y, hitPoints[1].x - hitPoints[0].x, hitPoints[2].y - hitPoints[1].y);

    lastTouch = thisTouch;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This code **almost** works, but it's not very accurate...as if there's rounding errors. It loses the proper aspect ratio over time, which is surprising...and why I used floats...but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: With the limited amount of information you posted, all I can offer is a hearty "good luck!"    Some code showing what approach you are trying now would be hugely helpful in getting an answer back from anybody.

Comment: I would show some code, but it's very long and just tracks some corner points which is obvious stuff. What I'm looking for is some pseudo-code for tracking a constrained rectangle or similar, if someone has any experience with it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to at least give us a starting point since we have no idea how your application is tracking things.

Comment: All you can do with a fixed-ratio rectangle is scaling and translation (and rotation, if you need it). For this case I would recommend to recognize pan and pitch gestures on entire view rather than moving the corners.